# glossaries optionally delete white space between long form and abbreviation

Tags: spacing, glossaries, acronyms

If one has an foreign acronym (here english) coupled with a german word one uses a `-` between both. Now I have the problem that the first occurrence of an acronym falls together with a coupled german word. In this case the whitespace between long form of the acronym and the acronym in parentheses needs to be removed (see MWE). So I'm looking for an optional argument for `\cgls` or another command like `\cglsnw` to delete this whitespace.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronymstyle{emfirst-long-sp-short}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-sp-short}%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-sp-short}%  
    \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\glsentrylong{##1}}##2\glsacspace{##1}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\Glsentrylong{##1}}##2\glsacspace{##1}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\glsentrylongpl{##1}}##2\glsacspace{##1}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}})%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\Glsentrylongpl{##1}}##2\glsacspace{##1}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}})%
    }%
}

\renewcommand*{\glsacspace}[1]{~}

\setacronymstyle{emfirst-long-sp-short}

\newcommand\newforeignacronym[5][]{\newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{\foreignlanguage{#5}{#4}}}

\makeglossaries

\glsenableentrycount

\newforeignacronym{am}{AM}{Application Management}{english}
\newforeignacronym{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machine}{english}


\begin{document}

The output from glossaries: \cgls{am}-Problem. \cgls{am}

Required output (without whitespace): \emph{Application Management}(AM)-Problem.

Required output for acronyms which are not coupled (so here with whitespace): \cgls{svm}. \cgls{svm}




\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which whitespace? I see **Application Management-Problem**

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm sorry I forget to add a second `\cgls{am}`. The command counts the times the acronym is used so I should use it at least two times.

Comment: A brute force method would be to remove the `~` in `\glsacspace` definition

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That would work for this example, but please consider the normal case where the acronym is not coupled with a german word. In that case the white space should be there. I will edit the MWE to make it clear.

Comment: I'll try to think about it later on. The mixing style of English and German is awful, in my point of view (I am German) ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you. If you have an idea how to prevent the mixing I'm happy to hear your suggestions. In computer science it is sometimes a bit difficult to find an adequate german word which is as precise as the english one. Of course the word `Application Management` in the MWE is just an example for which a good german word exists.

Comment: Try doing it in Welsh....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you have any new insights to that question?

Comment: @user2653422: I have posted a possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proposition: Use a redefinition of `\cgls` that has an 3rd argument which is optional and redefine `\glsacspace` to act whether the `\glsentrycurrcount` is `0` or greater than `0`.

This is not sufficient, however, since `\cgls{am}-foo` will not react on the `-foo` part without looking farther ahead, therefore use it this way

`\cgls{am}[Problem]`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\glsacspace}[1]{~}


\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\glossaries@@cgls\cgls
\let\glossaries@@glsacspace\glsacspace




\newif\ifthirdargused%

\RenewDocumentCommand{\cgls}{O{}mo}{%
  \IfValueT{#3}{%
    \thirdargusedtrue%
  }%
  \ifthirdargused
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\glsacspace}[1]{%
    \ifnum\glsentrycurrcount{##1} > 0% Is it > 0 then use the predefined spacing. 
    \glossaries@@glsacspace{##1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \glossaries@@cgls[#1]{#2}-#3%
  \endgroup
  \else
  \glossaries@@cgls[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
  \thirdargusedfalse%
  \let\glsacspace\glossaries@@glsacspace%
}

\makeatother


\newacronymstyle{emfirst-long-sp-short}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-sp-short}%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-sp-short}%  
    \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\glsentrylong{##1}}##2\glsacspace{##1}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\Glsentrylong{##1}}##2\glsacspace{##1}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\glsentrylongpl{##1}}##2\glsacspace{##1}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}})%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\Glsentrylongpl{##1}}##2\glsacspace{##1}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}})%
    }%
}


\glsenableentrycount



\setacronymstyle{emfirst-long-sp-short}

\newcommand\newforeignacronym[5][]{\newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{\foreignlanguage{#5}{#4}}}

\makeglossaries


\newforeignacronym{am}{AM}{Application Management}{english}
\newforeignacronym{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machine}{english}


\begin{document}

The output from glossaries: \cgls{am}[Problem]. 

Second usage: \cgls{am}

Required output (without whitespace): \emph{Application Management}(AM)-Problem.

Required output for acronyms which are not coupled (so here with whitespace): \cgls{svm}. 

Second usage: \cgls{svm}

%\cgls{am}-Problem

%\cgls{am}


\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user2653422: I thank you since I learned new features of `glossaries` again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility that doesn't modify internals.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newcommand*{\ishyphen}[2]{\ifdefstring{\glsinsert}{-}{#1}{#2}}

\newacronymstyle{emfirst-long-sp-short}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-sp-short}%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-sp-short}%  
    \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\glsentrylong{##1}}\ishyphen{}{##2\glsacspace{##1}}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})\ishyphen{-}{}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\Glsentrylong{##1}}\ishyphen{}{##2\glsacspace{##1}}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})\ishyphen{-}{}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\glsentrylongpl{##1}}\ishyphen{}{##2\glsacspace{##1}}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}})\ishyphen{-}{}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
        \emph{\Glsentrylongpl{##1}}\ishyphen{}{##2\glsacspace{##1}}%
        (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}})\ishyphen{-}{}%
    }%
}

\renewcommand*{\glsacspace}[1]{~}

\setacronymstyle{emfirst-long-sp-short}

\newcommand\newforeignacronym[5][]{\newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{\foreignlanguage{#5}{#4}}}

\makeglossaries

\glsenableentrycount

\newforeignacronym{am}{AM}{Application Management}{english}
\newforeignacronym{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machine}{english}


\begin{document}

The output from glossaries: \cgls{am}[-]Problem. \cgls{am}

Required output (without whitespace): \emph{Application Management}(AM)-Problem.

Required output for acronyms which are not coupled (so here with whitespace): \cgls{svm}. \cgls{svm}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This redefines the commands used in the full format to check `\glsinsert` (which is set to the final optional argument of commands like `\gls`/`\cgls`). This is actually the second argument of `\genacrfullformat` etc, so the test could be made against that instead in the event that it's used outside of `\cgls`.

[image: image of result]

Comment: Tried this solution today and found a part in my text where suddenly half of a line is missing and after that the paragraph continues normally. However, there is no command from the glossaries package in that paragraph. I couldn't reproduce this issue with a MWE. So some strange side effects take place due to the solution.